# How to setup full Clojure/ClojureScript stack?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop, leiningen, compojure

I need to make web app with clojure/clojurescript but i can't setup them properly.
I don't know how to start clojure and clojurescript REPLes in one port. Or how should i do that? Clojure backend works fine. Clojurescript works fine too. But i can't start them to work together in one port.
I use immutant/compojure, leiningen, figwheel. Can someone help me how to do that?

Edited:

First i started the backend REPL:

```
lein repl
***
ns=> (-main)
```

It started on 8080 port.
Second is figwheel REPL:

```
lein fighwheel
```

And it starts on 9500 port.
I've tried to start backend on same 9500 port but then figwheel says that port is busy.
I want to know how to build web app with clojurescript in frontend?

Comment: Please add a detailed example of what you have tried to do.

Comment: Open-ended questions like this one are usually not well received on Stack Overflow.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask


You might find more useful asking people on r/clojure https://www.reddit.com/r/Clojure/ and ClojureVerse https://clojureverse.org/.

Anyway, as @AlanThompson suggested, I would also recommend Luminus, which is kind of a CLI that helps you configure a web app with a Clojure backend and a ClojureScript frontend.

Comment: That's not what I asked but this helps me to find answer so I close this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at this book:

https://pragprog.com/titles/dswdcloj3/web-development-with-clojure-third-edition/

and this library:

https://luminusweb.com/

I have a template project in both CLJ and CLJS you can clone and experiment:

- Clojure Template (for backend):  https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template
- ClojureScript Template (for frontend):  https://github.com/io-tupelo/cljs-template

---

For deployment, you compile the CLJS code into a JavaScript "executable".  This JS code is typically referenced inside of `index.html` or similar HTML file (see `resources/public/index.html` in the CLJS template repo).

More info on the figwheel site:  [here](https://figwheel.org/tutorial#indexhtml)  and [here](https://figwheel.org/docs/your_own_page.html)